# JQuery .on() not working if passed functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Whenever I pass .on() functions as parameters it doesn't work, but if I define the function itself inside of the parameters, despite having the exact same code, it then works

For example, this does not work:

```
  function foo(){
    alert("Yo")
  }

  $(window).on("click", foo())
```

While this does:

```
  $(window).on("click", function(){
    alert("Yo")
  })
```

Comment: Use `foo` without brackets.

Comment: You're not "passing a function" - you're passing the "function result" - ie `var x = foo(); $(window).on("click", x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the function there.

You should pass its reference like this

```js
 $(window).on("click", foo)
```